# Add 0 padding to number in middle of string in ruby

Tags: ruby

This may be a really simple regex but its one of those problems that have proven hard to google.

I have error codes coming back from a third party system. They are supposed to be in the format:

> ZZZ##

where Z is Alpha and # is numeric. They are supposed to be 0 padded, but i'm finding that sometimes they come back

> ZZZ#

without the 0 padding.

Anyone know how i could add the 0 padding so i can use the string as an index to a hash?

Comment: How many zeroes do you want to add? Just one?

Comment: sorry ya. it should match that ZZZ## format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my take:

```
def pad str
  number = str.scan(/\d+/).first
  str[number] = "%02d" % number.to_i
  str
end

6.times do |n|
  puts pad "ZZZ#{7 + n}"
end

# >> ZZZ07
# >> ZZZ08
# >> ZZZ09
# >> ZZZ10
# >> ZZZ11
# >> ZZZ12
```

Reading:

- [String#[]=](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D)
- [Kernel#sprintf and  formatting flags](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf).

Answer (score 2):

```
fixed = str.gsub /([a-z]{3})(\d)(?=\D|\z)/i, '\10\2'
```

That says:

- Find three letters

  - …followed by a digit
  - …and make sure that then you see either a non-digit or the end of file
- and replace with the three letters (`\1`), a zero (`0`), and then the digit (`\2`)

To pad to an arbitrary length, you could:

```
# Pad to six digits
fixed = str.gsub /([a-z]{3})(\d+)/i do
  "%s%06d" % [ $1, $2.to_i ]
end
```

Comment: On SO you learn every day. :) Thank you, sir, for this neat trick with gsub and block :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's mine:

```
"ZZZ7".gsub(/\d+/){|x| "%02d" % x}
=> "ZZZ07"
```

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a million ways to do this but here's another look.

> str.gsub!(/[0-9]+/ , '0\0' ) if str.length < 5